# UIButton changes position after build

Tags: xcode, uibutton, uistoryboard

I encountered a weird problem with a UIView in my Application. I placed some UIButtons, UISlider, etc. on a View. Which looks like this:

[image: storyboard]

However, on the Simulator and on my iPhone it looks like this:
[image: simulator]

The button "+1 min" is not aligned with the other controls anymore.

The correct x-coordinate is 236. When I inspect the value in the debugger, I get 243.
I already checked the storyboard-file, which has the right value.

Why is it affecting only this button? And more importantly how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used Interface Builder.. Then definitely you have to do changes for autoresize in Interfacebuilder.. Try this it may solve your problem..

Comment: The buttons Autosizing was anchored right, instead of left, like all other buttons. Thanks for pointing me to the solution!